# Порядок отображения current_timestamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица , в нем current_timestamp , ну и данные получаются вот так

2020-01-04 12:28:05

Как сделать так чтобы данные были к примеру

12:28:05 04-01-2020 так

Comment: Форматировать как тебе нужно... есссно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для форматирования даты в MySQL исползуется функция DATE_FROMAT() Например:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%H:%m:%s %d-%m-%Y");
```

[Подробная документация к функции](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)